# I am trying to create a discord bot in python: when I run the bot.py file I get a TypeError. What should I do?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

BOT_TOKEN = 'REDACTED'
CHANNEL_ID = 1234
# Not actual CHANNEL_ID int due to privacy

bot = commands.bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send('Bot is ready')

bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[REDACTED INFO]/[REDACTED INFO]/bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    bot = commands.bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
**TypeError: 'module' object is not callable**
```

Comment: Please don't forget to mark it as answer, if it resolved your issue ;).

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a very simple typo issue there:

instead of `commands.bot` you should use `commands.Bot` (Bot with a capital B)
I would also store the intents in a variable, just for easier understanding

Here's the code:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

BOT_TOKEN = 'REDACTED'
CHANNEL_ID = 1234
intent = discord.Intents.all()
# Not actual CHANNEL_ID int due to privacy

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intent)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send('Bot is ready')

bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```